# Magento: How to Override Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action

Tags: magento, controller

I'd like to override `Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action` to add ACL checks to all front-end controller actions, similar to the way it's done in `Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action::preDispatch()` using `Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action::_isAllowed()`.

I've been able to create a `PackageName_ModuleName_Controller_Front_Action` that successfully extends `Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action`, include, and use it from any controller, however, this method would require that I now extend *every* Magento front-end controller that I want to add ACLs to in order to get them to use my new Front_Action. If I want a Deny, Allow priority policy setup, that's a lot of overriding.

If anyone knows how to properly extend this class in a more efficient manner it would certainly come in handy, otherwise I suppose I could work on an Allow, Deny priority, but that's still going to be a lot of overriding for my use case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of overriding `Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action` (which is almost impossible without, as you mentioned, overriding each front controller that is based on this class), you can put an observer on the `controller_action_predispatch` event, and use the `controller_action` value that is sent with it (and which should actually be on front-end the current instance of `Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action`).

Comment: While this answer does not override the Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action, it does work and seems to be a solid way to accomplish my goals. Thank you!