# magento predispatch event on for all action

Tags: magento, events

I want to unset a session key if the request is outside of customer account. Is there any event in magento which calls predispatch of every action. I will add action name check inside method. Just need to know event name which fires on predispatch every action

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Magento: How to Override Mage\_Core\_Controller\_Front\_Action](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17680604/magento-how-to-override-mage-core-controller-front-action)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below code:

```
<events>
    <controller_action_predispatch>
        <observers>
            <controller_action_before>
                <class>dispatcher/observer</class>
                <method>hookToControllerActionPreDispatch</method>
            </controller_action_before>
        </observers>
    </controller_action_predispatch>
</events>
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried this before your answer and works fine. Thank you for answer.